# How can i return an object using RunWorkerCompleted Event?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, c#-4.0

[I had given a return type for the event.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3w83.png)

[But i would like to return an object.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPPTM.png)

Comment: Please copy code as code to your question.

Comment: show your code what you are doing